# Silverlight Application IS Client Server or 3 Tier

Tags: silverlight

Suppose If I have silverlight application which consumes data through WCF.

Then We need to call this application has   Client Server architecture or 3 tier architecture.

What kind of architecutre is it. ?

Answer (score 0):

SOA: Service Orientated Architecture. You will actually find that a lot of "architectures" cross over each other. You will probably have aspects of Component Orientated and N tier as well.

Comment: So what is the  term we have to use to call such architecture ?

Comment: WCF is designed to a Sevice Orientated Architecture.